# ¿Cómo enviar y guardar valores de radio button en wordpress?

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress, insert, radiobutton

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario en wordpress en el que se le pregunte algo a cada usuario logueado hasta que complete ese dato, de tal forma que una vez completado e insertado en la bd no vuelva a aparecer el formulario. Lo he intentado por ejemplo con el sexo del usuario, pero no sé exactamente cómo enviar e insertarlo. ¿Alguna ayuda por favor? No da ningún error, pero tampoco inserta nada. Gracias por adelantado. He llegado hasta aquí:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

echo "<br>";
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";    //ID DEL USUARIO LOGGED
echo 'User sex: ' . $current_user->sexo . "\n";  //SEXO DEL USUARIO LOGGED   

$sexo=$current_user->sexo;

echo "<br>";

//COMPROBACIÓN DE QUE NO ESTÁ INSERTADO
if(( $sexo !== 'hombre' ) || ( $sexo !== 'mujer' ))
    {   
        echo "<br>";
        echo "NO EXISTE ESTE VALOR EN LA BD";
    }

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>"; 
?>
 //SI EL CAMPO ESTÁ VACÍO, MOSTRAMOS EL FORMULARIO
<form method = "post">
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="hombre" />HOMBRE
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="mujer" />MUJER
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">    
</form> 

<?php

if($_RESQUEST['genero'] == "hombre"){

    echo $_REQUEST['genero']."es un hombre";
}
if($_RESQUEST['genero'] == "mujer"){

    echo $_REQUEST['genero']."es una mujer";
}

global $wpdb;

$sexo = $_POST['genero'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'wp_users'      
        ('sexo') values ($sexo)";

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Comment: Empezando tienes mal llamado las peticiones : if($_RESQUEST['genero'] == "mujer"){ } , deberías renombrar a if($_REQUEST['genero'] == "mujer"){} etc etc , mejor dicho tienes mal escrito _REQUEST , es por eso que no te toma los valores para comparar.

Comment: Me temo que ahora que lo he corregido toma los valores para comparar, pero no ejecuta el "insert". Gracias pio. ¿Alguna idea para ello?

Comment: Primer paso , estar seguro de que la variable $sexo este guardando los datos enviados por la petición , debes hacer un var_dump($sexo); para saber si efectivamente esta guardando algún valor.

Comment: Segundo Paso : El query del insert lo veo erróneo, aquí un ejemplo insertando datos desde SQL a la tabla wp_users --> INSERT INTO `dbNAME`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('10', 'username', MD5('password'), 'Becky Arrowsmith', 'test@yourdomain.com', 'http://www.site.com/', '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Becky Arrowsmith');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias pio, he revisado la consulta sql y otras cosas que había por ahí y he conseguido que funcione todo. Ha quedado así, por si le sirve a alguien:

```
 global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo();

 echo "<br>";
 echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
 echo 'User sex: ' . $current_user->sexo . "\n";     

 $sexo = $current_user->sexo;

 global $wpdb;

 $consulta = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT '".$sexo."' FROM $wpdb->wp_users WHERE 
 ID = '".$current_user->ID."'" ); 

 var_dump($sexo); //NOS ASEGURAMOS DE QUE LA VARIABLE "SEXO" TIENE UN VALOR 
 //ASIGNADO CORRECTAMENTE.

 if( $sexo == null){ //IF DE LA CONSULTA    

  echo "<br>";

 echo "NO EXISTE ESTE VALOR EN LA BD";
 ?> 

<form method = "post">
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="hombre" />HOMBRE
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="mujer" />MUJER
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">    
</form>

<?php   

if($_REQUEST['genero'] == "hombre"){

    echo $_REQUEST['genero']. " es un hombre";

}
if($_REQUEST['genero'] == "mujer"){

    echo $_REQUEST['genero']. " es una mujer";

}   

echo "<br>";
$opcion = $_POST['genero'];
$sql = "UPDATE prueba.wp_users SET sexo=('".$opcion."') WHERE ID = 
('".$current_user->ID."')";

$wpdb->query($sql);

} /* FIN DEL PRIMER IF DE LA CONSULTA */ else{
 echo "EXISTE";
}
```